# iPad - How to debug hard browser crash?

Tags: ipad, debugging

We have a strange issue with Verizon iPads.  Anytime we send an email on this particular intranet site the browser crashes.  It will literally close itself down and bring you back to the desktop.

Does anyone know if iPad has some debugging tools for troubleshooting this kind of an issue?

This issue does not occur on desktop browsers, ATT iPad's or any other browser that has been tested.

Comment: Somebody just guessed that there was too much data being loaded and overloading memory.  They split some of the data out (didnt all need to be there) and it stopped crashing.  I'm still interested to know how I can troubleshoot these kinds of issues.

Comment: Did you analyze the crash report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually if the app crashes the browser, it could mean stack overflow. The app may have a recursive call that caused stack overflow,